# How do I draw a curve like this in xml res/drawable

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, layout, shapes

[image: Reference Image]

How would I go about drawing a shape like this?  I can't just use a half circle, because I want the edges to have a nice concave feel as they even out to flat.  After that I'm looking to add a border to just the top part.  How could this be done in xml?

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't use xml for this.  Use an image, possibly a vector drawable.

Comment: If I was to use an image, how could I do so without scaling issues and blurry pixels?  Or could you give me a little more direction on the vector drawable approach?  I was looking at the docs.